# Writing arbitrary mongoDB queries to PHP backend

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

Im in the start up phase of creating an internal system based on PHP and MongoDB. The users of this system are Javascript programmers and would like to be able to make custom queries to the  Mongo database from a frontend gui with arbitrary Mongo shell queries. Of course this would not be a problem at all if I forced them to to write the queries with proper PHP arrays etc, but i would definitely like to avoid this.

I am not quite sure how to approach a feature like this without writing some advanced methods being able to restructure the queries to proper formated arrays that can be used in MongoClient PHP. One approach would be making use of the i.e. MongoDB::execute() method and run the javascript on the database server - a method i don't fancy at all.

Im kindly asking if you have any ideas on how to achieve the requested functionalities to some extend.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a fun security hole. Heh.

Comment: Lag of security indeed, but in this case security is not an issue.

Comment: Security isn't an issue? What happens when someone accidentally deletes the database's contents?

Comment: I see your point, but loss of data is not vital. It would definitely suck, but that is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this : http://rockmongo.com/ ?

Comment: Rockmongo does not seem to fit this project, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: @PatrickPedersen RockMongo's a complete web UI for working with MongoDB. If you explain why it's not suitable it may help others answer.